# splitting data of a std::map into multiple std::vectors

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl, c++98

I have two classes: InitTable and InitEntry. InitTable contains a `std::map table` which stores the `ID` of an entry (car), and on object (`InitEntry`) which represents that car. Every `InitEntry` has 3 member variables:

1. `std::string ID`
2. `double speed`
3. `std::string heading`

My goal is to first store all the cars in the `std::map table`, and then iterate through that data structure, and try to organize the cars into clusters (`std::vector<InitEntry>`) based on common properties: `speed` & `heading`.

**Example:**

Lets assume we have 6 cars (ids 0 to 8)

- car0: id: "0", speed: 22, heading "N"
- car1: id: "1", speed: 26, heading "N"
- car2: id: "2", speed: 28, heading "W"
- car3: id: "3", speed: 12, heading "E"
- car4: id: "4", speed: 10, heading "E"
- car5: id: "5", speed: 45, heading "S"

To keep it simple, at this stage for me it would be enough to group the cars only based on heading. And the result would be:

```
std::vector clus1 = {car0, car1}
std::vector clus2 = {car2}
std::vector clus3 = {car3, car4}
std::vector clus4 = {car5}
```

Unfortunately, I do not have enough knowledge of C++ STL to be able to understand how to achieve this in C++.

---

**InitTable.h:**

```
    #include <InitEntry.h>


    class InitTable {
        public:
            InitTable();
            virtual ~InitTable();

            void clearTable();
            void addEntry(std::string ID, double speed, std::string heading);
            void deleteEntry(std::string ID);
            InitEntry* getEntry(std::string ID);


        protected:
            std::map<std::string, InitEntry*> table;
    };
```

**InitTable.cc:**

```
#include"InitTable.h"

InitTable::InitTable(){}


InitTable::~InitTable()
{
    clearTable();
}


void InitTable::clearTable()
{
    this->table.clear();
}

void InitTable::addEntry(std::string ID, double speed, std::string heading)
{
    InitEntry* newEntry = new InitEntry(ID, speed, heading);


    std::cout<< "server::InitTable: vehicle registered to the init table" << newEntry << endl;

    table.insert(std::make_pair(ID, newEntry));

}



void InitTable::deleteEntry(std::string ID)
{
    InitEntry* ie = getEntry(ID);
    if (ie != NULL)
    {
        table.erase(ID);
        delete ie;
    }
}

InitEntry* InitTable::getEntry(std::string ID)
{
    std::map<std::string, InitEntry*>::iterator it = table.find(ID);

    if (it != table.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "such entry does not exist" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

**InitEntry.h:**

```
class InitEntry {
    public:
        virtual ~InitEntry();
        InitEntry(std::string ID, double speed, std::string heading);
        std::string getID();


    protected:
        std::string sumoID;
        double speed;
        std::string heading;

};
```

**InitEntry.cc:**

```
#include "InitEntry.h"


InitEntry::InitEntry(std::string ID, double speed, std::string heading): ID(ID), speed(speed), heading(heading){}


InitEntry::~InitEntry(){}

std::string InitEntry::getID()
{
    return this->ID;
}
```

**EDIT 1: adding extra description (by request of @TomaszLewowski).**

Yes, my goal would be to organize the vehicles in clusters, by the heading, and then based on the speed. So initially there would be one big cluster of vehicles going on a certain direction, which later would need to be split into more clusters, based on speed. Lets say: vehicles heading "north", with speed: 0 - 20... with speed speed: 40 - 50...etc

Comment: Can you describe in a little more detail what do you want to achieve? e.g. do you seek for "all cars with same speed/direction" ? In such case probably your InitEntry shouldn't be a single record, but a vector of records. Or a reference/pointer to one.

Comment: Note: You have a memory leak. Store objects (not new objects) in your primary container. If your objects are polymorphic you might store std::uniique_ptr<base_type>

Comment: `std::map<std::string, InitEntry*> table;`  Why not just `std::map<std::string, InitEntry>` and skip the manual memory management?

Comment: @TomaszLewowski yes, your guess is right, that would be the goal that I want to achieve.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks for the suggestion. as I said I am not a very experienced programmer so any suggestion is welcome

Comment: @cross - Start with this cleaned up version of your code:  http://ideone.com/WUbqT1

Comment: wow @PaulMcKenzie, thanks a lot; but still how can I achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: @cross One question is if you update one of the InitEntry's in the map, does the corresponding `InitEntry` in the vector also gets updated?  If so, then the map (and vector) would be better suited for `std::shared_ptr<InitEntry>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if by "vector" you refer to the vector which is supposed to hold the final result of the cluster calculation, then the answer is: no, thne InitEntry in the vector need not be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing your `std::map<std::string, InitEntry*> table;` to:

```
std::vector<InitEntry> table;
```

You would then need to change your `*Entry` methods to:

```
void InitTable::addEntry(std::string ID, double speed, std::string heading)
{
    table.push_back(InitEntry(ID, speed, heading));
    std::cout<< "server::InitTable: vehicle registered to the init table" << table.back() << endl;
}

void InitTable::deleteEntry(std::string ID)
{
    auto it = remove_if(table.begin(), table.end(), [&](const auto& i){return i.getID() == ID;});
    table.resize(distance(table.begin(), it));
}

InitEntry* InitTable::getEntry(std::string ID)
{
    auto it = find_if(table.begin(), table.end(), [&](const auto& i){return i.getID() == ID;});

    if (it != table.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "such entry does not exist" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

To sort `table` you would need to decide what to sort by.

- To sort by ID: `std::sort(table.begin(), table.end(), [](const auto& first, const auto& second){return first.getID() < second.getID();});`
- To sort by speed: `std::sort(table.begin(), table.end(), [](const auto& first, const auto& second){return first.getSpeed() < second.getSpeed();});`
- To sort by heading: `std::sort(table.begin(), table.end(), [](const auto& first, const auto& second){return first.getHeading() < second.getHeading();});`

Obviously you'd need to add the getters to make these work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate over all elements (and I guess you don't), then only option is to keep these groups somewhere, and only some indices to them in the main table. This would look roughly like that:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::string ID;
typedef std::string Heading;
typedef double Speed;

struct Entry
{
    ID id;
    Speed speed;
    Heading heading;
};

class EntryProxy
{
public:
    EntryProxy(Entry* target) : entry(target)
    {}

    ID getId()
    {
        return entry->id;
    }

    Speed getSpeed()
    {
        return entry->speed;
    }

    Heading getHeading()
    {
        return entry->heading;
    }

private:
    Entry* entry;
};

class InitTable
{
public:
    const std::vector<EntryProxy>& getSameHeading(std::string id)
    {
        return groupedByHeadings.at(entries.at(id).heading);
    }

    const std::vector<EntryProxy>& getSimilarSpeed(std::string id)
    {
        return groupedBySpeed.at(calculateSpeedGroupIndex(entries.at(id).speed));
    }

    void addEntry(ID id, Speed speed, Heading heading)
    {
        Entry e{ id, speed, heading };
        auto record = entries.insert(std::make_pair(id, e)); // pair<iterator, bool>

        groupedByHeadings[record.first->second.heading].push_back(EntryProxy(&record.first->second));
        groupedBySpeed[calculateSpeedGroupIndex(record.first->second.speed)].push_back(EntryProxy(&record.first->second));
    }

    void deleteEntry(ID id)
    {
        auto entry = entries.find(id);
        assert(entry != entries.end());

        auto currentEntryHeadings = groupedByHeadings[entry->second.heading];
        currentEntryHeadings.erase(std::find_if(currentEntryHeadings.begin(), currentEntryHeadings.end(), [&entry](EntryProxy p){return p.getId() == entry->second.id; }));

        auto currentEntrySpeeds = groupedBySpeed[calculateSpeedGroupIndex(entry->second.speed)];
        currentEntrySpeeds.erase(std::find_if(currentEntrySpeeds.begin(), currentEntrySpeeds.end(), [&entry](EntryProxy p){return p.getId() == entry->second.id; }));

        entries.erase(id);
    }

    EntryProxy getEntry(ID id)
    {
        return EntryProxy(&entries.at(id));
    }

private:
    typedef int SpeedGroupIndex;

    SpeedGroupIndex calculateSpeedGroupIndex(Speed s)
    {
        // you may prefer a different implementation here

        return s / 10;
    }

    std::map<ID, Entry> entries;
    std::map<Heading, std::vector<EntryProxy> > groupedByHeadings;
    std::map<SpeedGroupIndex, std::vector<EntryProxy> > groupedBySpeed;
};
```

Grouping by Heading is pretty obvious, as it requires only a simple map. However, when it comes to speed it's a little tougher - you need to describe requirements for grouping (by implementing function `getSpeedGroupId`), as doubles shouldn't be used as map indices.

In case you prefer a more safe approach towards memory management you can substitute `Entry*` for `std::shared_ptr<Entry>` in `EntryProxy` and `Entry` for `std::shared_ptr<Entry>` in `InitTable::entries`. In that case you would also need to change creation from `Entry e{id, speed, heading` to `auto e = std::make_shared<Entry>(id, speed, heading)`.

If deleting is too complex for you, you may keep `EntryProxy` structures in a list, and a reference to specific iterators in `entries` map.

You may also not like the fact that groups are `EntryProxy` and single elements are `Entry` - in such case you may make `getEntry` also return `EntryProxy`.